# Catch/Handle Keydown Event From All Control Inside Groupbox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Is there any way to catch all keydown event from any controls like textboxes inside a groupbox using one event handler.?
I try groupbox_keydown, but it's not triggered. I try to make some research in msdn and they say groupbox cannot get focus, so the keydown event will never raised. Is there any workaround for it.?
KeyPreview already set to True.

Edit:
i have some textboxes inside a groupbox. most of them have default or predefined value. what i want is when user have filled the required data and want to skip some textboxes, he just need to press some key like ctrl+enter to excecuting a click on a button in that groupbox or calling a procedure.

Comment: There is more than one way to do this, you can't get the best answer if you don't explain why you need this.

Comment: i make some edit in description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work ok It iterates through the controls collection in the groupbox and adds the `.KeyDown` event to the example handler.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each ctl As Control In GroupBox1.Controls
        AddHandler ctl.KeyDown, AddressOf GroupBox1Controls_KeyDown
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBox1Controls_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(sender, Control).Name)
End Sub
```

It may be that there are controls that don't have a `.KeyDown` event, so you might want to add an empty `Try..Catch..End Try` block into the code like this, but I wouldn't recommend it as it could hide other problems with the code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each ctl As Control In GroupBox1.Controls
        Try
            AddHandler ctl.KeyDown, AddressOf GroupBox1Controls_KeyDown
        Catch
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: so I need to add every controls keydown there, one by one.? is there any other way so it will automatically include any control I add inside that groupbox.?

Comment: btw I've tried your suggestion, and it's working. so if there is no other way, then I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Possibly. Let me have a try of an idea.